# How can I solve the "Composer Update" Issue?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, code-composer

I have run "Composer Update" before, Then it runs smoothly. But from today I got the error mentioned in the image. Need help regarding the issue.

[image: The problem when I run Composer Update]

The error says:

In Process.php line 355:
Unable to launch a new process.

Note: `PHP artisan config:cache` and `PHP artisan cache:clear` runs smoothley

Comment: You have ran out of memory

Comment: How to solve this, have any demo??

Comment: Restart your machine to free memory or upgrade to a larger VPS

Comment: This happens when remotely accessing any server and running this command, but if the command executes from the same server then the problem does not occur

Comment: You should **never** run `composer update` on any remote server. Use your development system for this

Answer (score 0):

- you try delete composer.lock and run composer update --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Deleting composer.lock is usually not a good idea

Comment: This happens when remotely accessing any server and running this command, but if the command executes from the same server then the problem does not occur